# Fit regression model to the data with 3 dependent variables

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataset that contains different sediment fractions (particle sizes). The column 'Event' consists of unique sample sites. Each sample represents sedimentary material that is sorted by particle size. The data is given as a percentage.

[The example is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p3nlzhCs6FIjo15Zt1acH6la6DC6ITCJ).

For some samples, part of the data is missing (fractions of 10-5, 5-1 and <1 mcm). To clarify, these fractions should be derived from the **bold** column **<10 mcm** which is the sum of these fractions.

[image]

Ideally, grain size distribution should follow a normal distribution. But you can see from the data that such dependence is rarely traced here. In many cases, it is impossible to determine the mean of the distribution since the fractions' resolution is not enough.

Is there any way to recreate this data? If so, what model would you recommend (mainly I am working with R, however, python will be fine as well)?

Comment: Could you explain what "Sum(%)" means?  *Even for the rows with missing data* that column contains the value "100," suggesting nothing is missing at all.

Comment: The column 'Event' means the unique sample site. Each sample represents sedimentary material that is sorted by particle size. Actually, the 'Sum' column simply shows that all fractions together are 100%. However, the last three columns (not counting the sum) are divided into smaller subfractions (from the column '< 10 mcm') on 10 to 5, 5 to 1 and less than 1 micrometer. These three fractions should be determined (derived from the column '< 10 mcm').

Comment: However, their values depend on how much the particle size is shifted (either towards coarse particles or towards fine particles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use mutliple imputation (see the `mice` or `Hmisc` packages in `R`) to estimate the missing values. This requires that you can construct some model to predict these values using cells where you have complete data.

If you update your question to explain what variables might be useful in predicting the missing values then I might be able to help you more.

Comment: Indeed, one could interpret the original question as asking how to "construct some model to predict these values using cells where you have complete data."  These are *particle size distributions.* One approach would be to fit a parametric distribution model to the censored or truncated data.  (It's not yet clear whether they have been censored, as described, or truncated, as suggested by the column headers.)

Comment: I had the idea that it should possible to determine the dependence in descending or increasing distribution of particles (from a small fraction to large fraction and vice versa). And this dependence already should help to separate the column **<10 mcm** on these smaller fractions.

Comment: Also, I have updated the question a bit.